# Check if there is SQL injection in a string without access to the database (no parameters)

Tags: sql, database, string, security, sql-injection

I have a task to check and prove if there is a way to prevent SQL Injection without access to the database first - So no parameterized statements.
This basically means:

## Is there a way to parse SQL statement as a string using any kind of tool or framework that would prove that SQL has been injected into it.

### Any techniques available.

At first I had an idea to check if SQL matches a certain pattern like this:

Let `somewhere` be any kind of string that user can type in.
This is my SQL:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM somewhere
```

This statement has a pattern that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT SOME_VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Then let's say user wrote  `someTable WHERE 1=1;`  into the `somewhere` variable - (I know its not the smartest of SQL Injections)

But the point is now I have a statement that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM someTable WHERE 1=1;
```

Which effectively gives us a statement that has a pattern like this:

```sql
SELECT SOME_VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITION
```

Which does not match the initial pattern:

```sql
SELECT SOME_VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Is that a correct way to check if SQL has been injected? I haven't found any tools that actually use this technique, or any other technique than just parameters (which require connection to the database). Don't worry - I know that parameters are the way to go, this task is about having no connection to the database.

Comment: The correct way is to not let the user pass any parameters as string but only as parameters. Also, what rdbms and programming language are you referring to? Why someone gave you this task?

Comment: PostgreSql and C# in my case, but the implementation and language are irrelevant. And I'm not trying to avoid parameters, I know they should be used. It is just a completely different task, I just need to find a workaround - If there is none - That's fine, but some proof would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

It would be an idea if you block certain keywords and symbols like 'WHERE', 'AND', 'OR', ';', and '='.

But this is just a naive approach and for production, you should use parameterized statements.

Comment: I know that parameterized statements are the way to go. This is just a different kind of question.